# Sort data by factor and output into a matrix (or df) R

Tags: r

I have looked through other posts and I think I have an idea of what I could do, but I want to be clear!

I have a very large data frame that contains 4 variables and a number of rows.

```
  Chain ResId ResNum    Energy
1     C   O17    500 -37.03670
2     A   ARG      8  -0.84560
3     A   LEU     24  -0.56739
4     A   ASP     25  -0.98583
5     B   ARG      8  -0.64880
6     B   LEU     24  -0.58380
7     B   ASP     25  -0.85930
```

Each row contains CHAIN (A, B, or C), ResID, ResNum, and Energy. I would like to sort this data so that all of the energy values belonging to a specific Resid and num in each chain are clustered together. By cluster I mean all of the values for "ARG 8" are grouped or all of the rows containing "ARG 8" are grouped. I don't know which is more efficient. Ideally, I would like the output for all residues to be

```
ARG 8
0.000
0.000
0.000
```

where the "0.000" are the energy values for ARG 8 or O17 and so on.

Sorry for the header breaks, I wanted the data to be clean, but I can't insert images.

**data**

```
structure(list(Chain = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), ResId = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("ARG", "ASP", "LEU", "O17"
), class = "factor"), ResNum = c(500L, 8L, 24L, 25L, 8L, 24L, 
25L), Energy = c(-37.0367, -0.8456, -0.56739, -0.98583, -0.6488, 
-0.5838, -0.8593)), .Names = c("Chain", "ResId", "ResNum", "Energy"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Have you tried `order` or `arrange` from `dplyr`? i.e. `arrange(df,ResId, ResNum)`

Comment: @D.A. for future ref: to hightlight /format code you indent the relevant lines by four spaces or hightlight a block of code and select  `{ }`. It is also useful to add data in the structured format: use `dput(data[1:7, ])`

Comment: `reshape(dat, idvar=c("ResId", "ResNum"), direction="wide", timevar="Chain", v.names="Energy")` possibly

Comment: While i think converting to wide is the more useful way to process your data, you can get closer to your expected outout by putting each ResId/ResNum in a list: `s <- split(dat[c("Chain", "Energy")], list(dat$ResId, dat$ResNum)) ; s[!!sapply(s, nrow)]`

Comment: Hello user20650, I have tried both of your suggestions and the 2nd suggestion seems to work pretty well for me. However, I am trying to apply a function from another package and some standard functions over the list and I'm running into errors.

Comment: HI DA; ok, so you find the second solution more useful. If you want to apply a function over a list, the `apply` functions are useful (`lapply`, `sapply`, ...).  Perhaps the `ave` or `aggregate` functions could be useful (to avoid the split) but without more info, i cannot offer anythinfg else. I think it might be worth asking a new question, describing overall what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, the output you are most likely looking for is:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ResId~Chain, value.var= 'Energy')
  ResId        A       B        C
1   ARG -0.84560 -0.6488       NA
2   ASP -0.98583 -0.8593       NA
3   LEU -0.56739 -0.5838       NA
4   O17       NA      NA -37.0367
```

This will put the values together. You can further specify based on your desired output.

```
df[order(df$ResId), ]
  Chain ResId ResNum    Energy
2     A   ARG      8  -0.84560
5     B   ARG      8  -0.64880
4     A   ASP     25  -0.98583
7     B   ASP     25  -0.85930
3     A   LEU     24  -0.56739
6     B   LEU     24  -0.58380
1     C   O17    500 -37.03670

#With dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(ResId)
  Chain ResId ResNum    Energy
1     A   ARG      8  -0.84560
2     B   ARG      8  -0.64880
3     A   ASP     25  -0.98583
4     B   ASP     25  -0.85930
5     A   LEU     24  -0.56739
6     B   LEU     24  -0.58380
7     C   O17    500 -37.03670
```

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = '
Chain ResId ResNum Energy

C O17 500 -37.0367

A ARG 8 -0.8456

A LEU 24 -0.56739

A ASP 25 -0.98583

B ARG 8 -0.6488

B LEU 24 -0.5838

B ASP 25 -0.8593', header=T)
```

Comment: Hello, I've managed to get the data ordered as you have is above. Now I want to reshape or condense the data so that I can apply a function for each resid/resnum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to `wide` format

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ResId+ResNum~paste0('Energy.',Chain), value.var='Energy')
#   ResId ResNum Energy.A Energy.B Energy.C
#1   ARG      8 -0.84560  -0.6488       NA
#2   ASP     25 -0.98583  -0.8593       NA
#3   LEU     24 -0.56739  -0.5838       NA
#4   O17    500       NA       NA -37.0367
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- df[order(df$Chain, df$ResId, df$ResNum),]
```

where df is the name of your dataframe. This should order it for you.

Comment: Why would you use `cbind` on a data frame like that?

Comment: I tested it on some of my own code and it worked fine - the reason to use it is so that the order function knows to order the data by multiple columns

Comment: Based on your code applied on the example showed here, I get some additional NA rows

Comment: Can you post the data that you used?

Comment: I forgot part of the code... my bad.. the order function is obviously necessary

Comment: The code is not producing the desired output of the OP. Please post the data that was used for a reproducible result. Or at least post the result that you get in your terminal.

Comment: Your right, it wasn't working before but should be working now if he wants to sort by 3 columns.